# SerializationBinder with List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, binaryformatter

I'm trying to make the `BinaryFormatter` work across different versions of my assembly. The actual class I want to deserialize to is exactly the same in each assembly version, but on deserialization, because the objects are serialized include the assembly name they came from, the `BinaryFormatter` is complaining that it can't find the right assembly. So I created a custom `SerializationBinder` that tells the `BinaryFormatter` to always deserialize to the current assembly version.

My scheme works and can deserialize objects correctly, but it doesn't work if my object is a List of T, where T was a type serialized from an older version of my assembly.

Is there some way to make this work with Lists and other generic types where the type parameter is a class from my assembly?

```
//the object i want to deserialize
class MyObject
{
     public string Name{get;set;}
}

//my binder class
class MyBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    static string assemblyToUse = typeof (MyObject).Assembly.FullName;
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        var isMyAssembly = assemblyName.StartsWith("oldAssemblyName");
        var assemblyNameToUse = isMyAssembly ? assemblyToUse : assemblyName;
        var tn = typeName + ", " + assemblyNameToUse;
        return Type.GetType(tn);            
    }
}


//my deserialize method
static object BinaryDeserialize(string input)
{
    var arr = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    var ms = new MemoryStream(arr);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Binder = new MyBinder();
    var obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);

    return obj;
}

static void Test()
{
    //this works
    //serialized(new MyObject());
    var str = ReadSerialized_MyObject();  
    var obj = BinaryDeserialize(str);

    //this doesn't work
    //serialized(new List<MyObject>());
    var str2 = ReadSerialized_List_of_MyObject(); 
    var obj = BinaryDeserialize(str2);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you serialized an instance of List< MyClass > from your version 1.0.0.0 assembly, the SerializationBinder.BindToType function will be asked to provide this type:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyAssembly.MyClass, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=12345678901234567890]]
```

In order to remap the List< MyClass > type to your version 2.0.0.0 assembly, you need to change the type name to this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyAssembly.MyClass, MyAssembly]]
```

The main point to note, is that the assembly name is not fully qualified. If you try to fully qualify the assembly name with a 2.0.0.0 version number, it will not work.

Comment: this is what i ended up doing... points to you since i forgot to answer this myself

Comment: This just might save my life. Sending this 1000+ List is about 3MB message size once SOAPified using an endpoint of a basicHttpBinding WCF service. Now that I'm binary encoding the message by hand, have it down to around .4MB. You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

Application A creates a Serialized Binary formatter file "SerializedList.bin" which contains List(Result) where Result is the Serializable object. 
Now Application B wants to DeSerialize the file and load into List(Result) object. 
This is how I got it working..

Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxremoting/thread/eec2b7a6-65f8-42d1-ad4f-409f46bdad61

Application A Assembly Name is "Serialize"
Application B Assembly Name is "DeSerialize"

Application A Code(Serialize):

```
namespace Serialize
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        List<Result> result = ;//Get From DB

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream sStream = new FileStream(
            "SerializedList.bin",
            FileMode.CreateNew,
            FileAccess.Write,
            FileShare.None);

        formatter.Serialize(sStream, result);
        sStream.Close();           
    }
}
```

}

Some Result Object:

```
[Serializable]
public class Result
{
    public decimal CONTACT_ID { get; set; }
    public decimal INSTITUTION_NBR { get; set; }
}
```

Application B Code (DeSerialize):

```
namespace DeSerialize
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        string fromTypeName = "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Serialize.Result, Serialize, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]";
        string fromTypeName1 = "Serialize.Result";

        string toTypename = "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DeSerialize.Result]";
        string toTypename1 = "DeSerialize.Result";
        string toTypeAssemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;

        DictionarySerializationBinder dic = new DictionarySerializationBinder();
        dic.AddBinding(fromTypeName, toTypename);
        dic.AddAssemblyQualifiedTypeBinding(fromTypeName1, toTypename1, toTypeAssemblyName);

        formatter.Binder = dic;

        Stream dStream = new FileStream(
            "SerializeList.bin",
            FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read,
            FileShare.Read);

        List<Result> listDS =
            (List<Result>)formatter.Deserialize(dStream);

        dStream.Close();
    }
}

sealed class DictionarySerializationBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    Dictionary<string, Type> _typeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        Type typeToReturn;

        if (_typeDictionary.TryGetValue(typeName, out typeToReturn))
        {
            return typeToReturn;
        }

        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void AddBinding(string fromTypeName, string toTypeName)
    {

        Type toType = Type.GetType(toTypeName);

        if (toType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
            "Help, I could not convert '{0}' to a valid type.", toTypeName));
        }

        _typeDictionary.Add(fromTypeName, toType);

    }

    public void AddAssemblyQualifiedTypeBinding(string fromTypeName, string toTypeName, string toTypeAssemblyName)
    {

        Type typeToSerializeTo = GetAssemblyQualifiedType(toTypeAssemblyName, toTypeName);

        if (typeToSerializeTo == null)
        {

            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(

            "Help, I could not convert '{0}' to a valid type.", toTypeName));

        }

        _typeDictionary.Add(fromTypeName, typeToSerializeTo);

    }

    private static Type GetAssemblyQualifiedType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {

        return Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyName));

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just handle `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event and return the desired assembly when calling `Type.GetType` method. That's as simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use more simple construction like this in BindToType function:

```
var tn = typeof(List<MyClass>).AssemblyQualifiedName;
return Type.GetType(tn, true)
```

Last parameter 'true' will give you error message (with trace) if your type definition is incorrect. It will save you a lot of time in debugging later.