# Format of generic type namein SerializationBinder

Tags: c#, .net, generics, serialization, reflection

I'm using a `SerializationBinder` to bind to the current types in case of changes of type names. Therefore I have a dictionary that binds old type names to the new names.

```
dict.Add("Old.Namespace.OldTypeName", "New.Namespace.NewName");
```

I can use this dictionary to get the type in the `Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)` method of the `SerializationBinder`. If this type is used in generic types, I must also find the new type of the generic. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8015241/498298) explained how to do this for `List<T>`. I am wondering if there is a standardized format of generic type names, so that I can use some kind of regex to get the new type for all kind of generics.

```
public class TypeDictionary
{
    private Dictionary<string, Type> bindings_ =
        new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    public void AddBinding(string oldTypeString, Type newType)
    {
        bindings_.Add(oldTypeString, newType);
    }

    public Type NewType(string oldTypeString)
    {
        // How should this be implemented:
        if (IsGeneric(oldTypeString))
            return NewGenericType(oldTypeString);

        Type newType;
        if (bindings_.TryGetValue(oldTypeString, out newType))
            return newType;
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Most strings I have seen so far are as `List<T>` like this

```
 Namespace.TypeName`1[[MyAssembly.MyClass, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

Is it save to just look for `"[[MyAssembly.MyClass,"` to detect a generic Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full name of the generic type contains a backtick character (`) followed by a digit that specifies the number of type arguments, followed by a square bracket containing each type argument (possibly in in an additional square bracket).

So `List<String>` is written like

```
  List`1[[String]]
```

and `Dictionary<String, Object>` like

```
  Dictionary`2[[String],[Object]]
```

and `Func<String, Object, Guid>` like

```
  Func`3[[String],[Object],[Guid]]
```

except that full namespace is given for the generic type, and full namespace, assembly, version, culture, and public key token are given for each type argument.

On the other hand, the full name of a non-generic type contains neither backtricks nor square brackets. Maybe you can write your regex with this in mind?

PS! If you use `oldType.ToString()` instead of `oldType.FullName` you get a somewhat shorter string that does not include assembly, culture, etc.

Comment: This is what I have seen on most types, but then I get this one: `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection\`1+SimpleMonitor[[MyNS.MyClass, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]`. Do you know what this `+SimpleMonitor` part is?

Comment: It's a nested type. That means a type defined inside another type, like if you do `class ObservableCollection<T> { public class SimpleMonitor { } }`. So "plus" means nested type.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want to replace all references to `MyClass`, whether they are generic type parameters of other classes or not.

So, you just need to look for your type names anywhere in the type name string.

If you replace all the type names in your dictionary, you get a new string which you can pass to [Type.GetType( string typeName )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx). This gives you the new `Type` instance which you can return from `BindToType`.

It gets a bit tricky when the types you are replacing are themselves generic.

Comment: Simple replacement was my first try but it gets difficult if there is a `MyClassCalculator`. Maybe I should try to replace `[MyClass,` with `[MyNewClass,` if there is no exact match.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any complex procedure. Suppose you are about to deserialize a type name like this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Myclass, MyNameSpace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

Simply, handle `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event and then call `Type.GetType` method with above type name. It will raise the event and there, you can return whatever assembly you want.